# How does Lovefield stand out from other in-browser JavaScript databases?

Tags: javascript, database, rdbms, lovefield

[Lovefield](https://github.com/google/lovefield) is a new cross-browser, SQL-like RDBMS in JavaScript. What are its advantages over existing client-side JS database libraries, like:

- YDN-DB - github.com/yathit/ydn-db
- TaffyDB - taffydb.com
- HTML5SQL.JS - html5sql.com
- AlaSQL.js - github.com/agershun/alasql

Comment: Sad it was closed, I would like to find out pros and cons of it.